# Login issue in chrome while using selenium and robotframework

Tags: windows, google-chrome, authentication, robotframework, selenium2library

I am using selenium2library and robotframework
Using chrome as the browser
Login is working manually but not with Script with the same username and password. 
I am using recent chrome and chrome driver(83 version). 
Using selenium2Library
Also, after entering username and password through the script i am fetching the value from UI using get value and compared with the input values. Both the values are same. Then also after clicking login button i am getting wrong credentials error

In the opened browser through script(when i pause the execution), Manually i am able to enter username and password, this is working fine. 
But input values through script is not working

What might be the issue?
PFB:

```
Open Browser    <URL>   browser=chrome  executable_path=D:\\chromedriver.exe
Sleep   30s     
Wait Until Page Contains Element    //input[@id="username"]     
Input Text  //input[@id="username"] <USERNAME?
Input Text  //input[@id="password"]     <PASSWORD>  
Press Keys  //input[@id="password"] Enter   
comment Click Element   //*[@id="sign_in"]  
Sleep   20s     
Wait Until Page Contains Element    <XPATH> timeout=30s 


Confirguration in windows:
robotframework-3.1.2
robotframework-autoitlibrary-1.2.5
robotframework-imagelibrary-0.1.1
robotframework-ride                1.7.4.1
robotframework-selenium2library    3.0.0
robotframework-seleniumlibrary     4.4.0

Chrome- 83.04
 ChromeDriver 83.0.4103.39
```

Comment: Please add your RF code and the related log messages and error messages etc.

Comment: Added the code, but it s not dependent on the code, there is no error message, the page is not getting loaded after login, instead it is throwing wrong username and password. Tried checking the username and password by doing get value of that xpath and comparing with input which is proper. But it is throwing wrong username and password. Not sure why

Comment: @pavelsaman, can u pls help. or tell me the working setup for robotframework recent version. so that i can downgrade or upgrade my version